# How to conditionally change cells in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a time column which is of type object.

I would like to add a leading 0 when the length of the time is 3.

so '1200' should stay the same but '900' should be converted to '0900'

My guess was to do something like:

```
sample['Time'] = ('0' + sample['Time']) if sample['Time'].str.len() == 3 else sample['Time']
```

However I get this error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Does `sample['Time'].str.zfill(4)` return what you expect?

Comment: Yes it does. Didn't know that function exists. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the column as a str and use:

```
sample['Time'] = sample['Time'].str.zfill(4)
```

Note - this will make all strings at least 4 characters - zero padded from the front. For strings longer than length 4 - it'll do nothing.

eg:

```
s = pd.Series(['900', '1200', '40', '4', '', float('nan'), '999999'])
r = s.str.zfill(4)
```

Gives you an `r` of:

```
0      0900    # <- prefixed
1      1200    # <- unchanged
2      0040
3      0004
4      0000
5       NaN    # <- nothing happens here
6    999999    # <- string remains 6 characters
```